# Quotient of a torsion free module is torsion free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

If $R$ is an integral domain and $M$ is a torsion-free $R$ module. Then is $M/IM$ a torsion-free $R/I$ module, where $I\neq 0$ is an ideal of $R$?

I think there is an obvious counterexample to it, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Say $R$ is an integral domain and $I \neq 0$, $M=R$.

Comment: Is $R/IR$ supposed to be something other than $R/I$?

Comment: No, it is the same thing

Comment: Ok well then to zoom in a little on Mindlack's hint: take $R=M=\mathbb{Z}$. Choose just about any ideal you like....

Comment: That just means that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$  module. How is this a counterexample?

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry. I wasn't reading carefully. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ isn't torsion-free as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but that's not what you asked. (Btw: put `@username` in comments to make sure they're seen by the person they're directed to.)

Comment: @halrankard Okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to write down the naive proof attempt, see where it goes wrong, and extract a counterexample from it :

Let $x\in M/IM, r\in R/I$ such that $rx = 0$. Then, pulling back to $M$ and $R$, we hvae $rx \in IM$.

The point is that this does not imply $x\in IM$ or $r\in I$.

For instance, pick $I$ which is not a prime ideal, so for instance $xy\in I,x\notin I, y\notin I$ and $M=R$. Then in $R/I$, you get $xy = 0$, but $x\not = 0$ in $R/I$, $y\not = 0$ in $M/IM$ ($=R/I$).

e.g. $\mathbb Z/6$ is not torsion-free as a $\mathbb Z/6$-module, because $2\times 3=  0$

($R$ is torsion-free as an $R$-module if and only if it's an integral domain)

Here's an example where $r$ is not a zero divisor, in fact an example where $R/I$ is integral : let $R=\mathbb Z[X]$ and $M = \bigoplus_\mathbb N \mathbb Z$, where $X$ acts by shifting copies of $\mathbb Z$ and multiplying by $2$, that is, $n$ in position $i$ is sent by $X$ to $2n$ in position $i+1$.

This is torsion free : indeed, if $P=a_n X^n +$ lower degree terms is a nonzero polynomial acting on some element whose maximal nonzero coordinate is $x$ in position $r$, then $P\cdot x$ has $2^n a_n x$ in position $r+n$ (everyone else is sent to lower positions), which is nonzero.

However, with $I=(X), R/I \cong \mathbb Z$ and $M/IM$ has torsion, for instance $1$ in degree $2$ is $2$-torsion.

Comment: Thanks @Maxime Ramzi.

Comment: My understanding is that a module $M$ over a ring $R$ is "torsion-free" if whenever $rx=0$ (with $r\in R$ and $x\in M$) either $x=0$ or $r$ is a zero-divisor. Under this definition, there is no issue with $\mathbb{Z}/6$, and any ring $R$ is torsion-free as an $R$-module.

Comment: @halrankard : I guess it depends on the definition of "torsion-free" in non-integral contexts - I'm not sure there's a consensus on that one. But in any case, let me add an example with your definition

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Nice!

Comment: @halrankard : thanks ! I wonder how simple the examples can be now haha (I fear it might be related to some hard homological algebra, see e.g. the homological conjectures)

Comment: Yes, it's an interesting question, but not exactly my area. My initial thought was also to do something with $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$, but after checking Wikipedia I saw that  "torsion-free" didn't (necessarily) mean what I thought it meant.